# Jquery .last() equivalence to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, converters

Hi I'm converting Some jquery code to javascript.
what is I'm trying to convert is:

```
frame.contents().find("div[class='footNote']").remove();
               var last = frame.contents().find("div").last();

               _.each($scope.currencyNotes, function (item) {
                   var footNote = $("<div class='footNote' />");
                   footNote.css('font-size', '13px');
                   

                   var fFootNote =footNote.appendTo(last);
                   fFootNote.html("<div style='float:left;width:25px'>" + item.Id + "</div>" + " <div style='float:left;width:80%'>" + item.Text + "</div>");
               });
```

what have i can manage to convert by googling is

```
 frame.contentDocument.querySelector("div[class='footNote']").parentNode.removeChild(frame);
      var last = frame.contentDocument.querySelector("div").last();

      Array.from(this.currenyNotes).forEach((item:any) => {
        //todo
        var footNote = document.createElement("div class='footNote' ");
        footNote.style.fontSize = "13px";
       
        

        var fFootNote = footNote.appendChild(last);
        fFootNote.innerHTML("<div style='float:left;width:25px'>" + item.Id + "</div>" + " <div style='float:left;width:80%'>" + item.Text + "</div>");
```

I have some problem with converting `.last()`.when i replaced with last with `last = frame.contentDocument.querySelector("div").lastChild;` or `last = frame.contentDocument.querySelector("div").lastElementChild;` it shows `fFootNote.innerHTML` error:Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'  .

if i convert `.last()` with i replaced with last with `last = frame.contentDocument.querySelectorAll("div")` it shows no option for replacing `.last()`

so my question is how can am i going write way?how to convert `.last()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi :) Welcome to stackoverflow !

If you use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that it returns can be converted to an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) on which you can call [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```
// something like this

let last = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).pop();
```

Comment: your solution  showing in the last line fFootNote.innerHtml :This expression is not callable.Type 'String' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Comment: that error is not related to the code I posted ... you should investigate a bit and if necessary ask another question ... that's how it works here :)

Comment: thanks i got the solve the prob was `fFootNote.innerHTML("<div style='float:left;width:25px'>" + item.Id + "</div>" + " <div style='float:left;width:80%'>" + item.Text + "</div>");` was incorrect it will be `fFootNote.innerHTML = ("<div style='float:left;width:25px'>" + item.Id + "</div>" + " <div style='float:left;width:80%'>" + item.Text + "</div>");`